# How to use an interface in business logic

Tags: php, design-patterns, interface

How do I use an interface in my business logic? For example, if I have an interface for a gateway like this like this:

```
<?php
    interface Gateway()
    {
        function writeToDatabase();
        function readFromDatabase();
    }
?>
```

And an implementation of it for a specific database:

```
<?php
    class MySQL implements Gateway
    {
       public function writeToDatabase()
       {
          //Write data to database here....
       }

       public function readFromDatabase()
       {
          //Read data from database here...
       }
   }
?>
```

How do I use the gateway interface in my business logic without making a specific reference to the MySQL class? I can type hint the interface in a class constructor like this:

```
<?php
    class BusinessClass
    {
        private $gateway;

        public function __construct(Gateway $gateway)
        {
           $this->gateway = $gateway;
        }
    }
 ?>
```

But I haven't been able to figure out a way to instantiate a new object that uses the Gateway interface without saying:

```
$gateway = new MySQL();
```

And I'd rather not do that because if I decided to write another implementation of the Gateway interface for a different database I would have to change all the hard references in my business logic from 'MySQL' to the new implementation. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an [Abstract Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern). Whith this pattern you just configure the concrete factory once in one point of your code and nothing more.

If you think is overdesign because your app is a lot of simple just do something like this:

```
Public class GatewayFactory{

Public static IGateWay CreateGateway(){

//read app configuration file, constant or whatever you use to configure gatewaytype in design time or runtime
string gateWayType = readGatewayTypeCofiguration();
if (gateWayType = Constants.MySQL) {return New MySQL()}//Use Constants! Don't hardcode literal Strings
if (gateWayType = Constants.SQLServer) {return New SQLServer()}
//etc...

  }
}
```

When GateWay changes just change the configuration and everything else remains untouched.

Comment: Awesome, that was the answer I was looking for. Thank you!